# is_authenticated()

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Доступ к сайту строго через login и password. Вопрос, если есть url /search, /test1, /test2 и т.д. чтобы не было не санкционированном доступа каждый раз использовать if request.user.is_authenticated() для проверки url?

```
def search(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
     .......

def tes1(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
     .......
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Декоратор login_required](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/topics/auth.html#the-login-required-decorator)

> `login_required()` does the following:
>
> - If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to `settings.LOGIN_URL`, passing the current absolute path in the query string. Example: `/accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/`.
> - If the user is logged in, execute the view normally. The view code is free to assume the user is logged in.